# How to send multimedia messages with android intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to send an multimedia message(with an image) through an intent.How should I build the intent?
I've tried the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/png");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/documents/aaa.png")));
```

I can select mms app(Textra) from chooser dialog to send the image. But the chooser dialog lists other apps(such as Google Keep).

Then I tried this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
```

Only mms apps appears now.But I don't know how to attach my image.
Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/documents/aaa.png")));
intent.setType("image/png");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Google replaced that app with Hangouts in 4.4.2.So it will crash because specified app is not found.It works after I set the class name to my default mms app.However, I want an app chooser dialog but not specified app in my code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

try this may help,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
intent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "write some text here"); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/documents/whatever.png")));
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Google replaced that app with Hangouts in 4.4.2.So it will crash because specified app is not found.It works after I set the class name to my default mms app.However, I want an app chooser dialog but not specified app in my code. Is it possible?